# Interpreting Literal Run Time of a Program in Unix

Tags: c, unix, runtime

I ran a C program (table.c) using the command:

```
time table
```

to give me the running time and I got:

```
0.104u   1.179s   0:01.31   96.9%      0+0k 0+48io 0pf+0w
```

I have a few questions:

Q1: What does all this mean?

Q2: Why are these numbers changing every time I execute my program?

Comment: What operating system is this? That's not what the output of Linux's `time` usually looks like. Also, it'd be helpful if you at least gave us an idea of what `table.c` does.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It is a hash table inserts, deletes, fetches, probes (checks to see if a value is there). I am running this program in Unix, as I indicated in the tag.

Comment: What version? What flavor? What userspace? I saw the tag, but that doesn't give me enough information to find any documentation. Did you try running `man time` on your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: What does all this mean?

The first value (`u`) is the amount of time that your program spent in *user* context. That means, how long did *your* code spend running.

The second value (`s`) is the amount of time that your program spent in *system* context. Meaning, during the execution of your program, how long did it spend in the kernel, handling system calls that your program made.

The third value is the total amount of time your program ran for, including *user*, *system*, and *sleeping* which isn't shown.

I believe if you do the math, you'll see that your program was *running* (not *sleeping*) for 96.9% of the time from when it started, until it ended.

> Q2: Why are these numbers changing every time I execute my program?

Because you're running on a real desktop system, with a preemptive operating system, that's also running other programs, and handling external events like hard disk activity, and network traffic. You can't possibly expect a program to run with the *exact* same timing every time. <sup>1</sup>

<sup>1 - This isn't true for a specially-designed "Real-Time OS" which are often used in embedded systems, e.g. automotive.</sup>

Comment: What about, 0+0k 0+48io 0pf+0w ? What do those represent? I noticed that the 3rd one never changes.

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon Can you please answer the question I asked in the comments above?

Comment: It's a hash table. It inserts, deletes, fetches, probes (checks to see if it's there).